# Best way to automatic change update_time in mongoengine only under some conditions

Tags: mongoengine

Say I defined a model `Story`, and in my `save` method I automatically update the `update_time` field:

```
class Article(Document):
    ...
    content = StringField()
    likes = IntField(default=0)
    some_mark = BooleanField()
    update_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def save(...)
        self.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        ...
```

But I would NOT like to only update the `update_time` when only the `likes` count or `some_mark` are changed. Or, if I only want to update the `update_time` when some fields like the `content` is changed. What will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `._changed_fields` attribute on your Document class to check the fields that were changed

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
    enter code here

p = Person(name='John').save()

print(p._changed_fields)   # []

p.name = 'Bob'
print(p._changed_fields)   # ['name']
```